# Change in the rule engine from Classic to Decision rule engine

Tags: ibm-odm

Developed the decision service in classic rule engine and at the end when i change the rule engine from Classic rule engine from Decision engine then all the Virtual Methods IRL has been removed and getters, setters also not available in the BOM project. Yes i'm aware Decision engine uses ARL and Classic Rule engine IRL.

How can i change to Decision Rule engine without loss of Virtual Methods, Getters and Setters?

Currently using IBM ODM 8.7.1.2 version

Comment: You haven't asked a question...

Comment: My Virtual method IRLs are Removed which i don't want to happen. When i change it back to Classic Rule engine , everything is normal. Help me how can we solve it

Answer (score 1):

Your IRL should be translated to ARL when you first set the execution to be with the Decision Engine.  This is explained here:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSQP76_8.9.1/com.ibm.odm.dserver.rules.designer.run/executing_decision_topics/con_decision_engine.html

It is possible for some IRL code to not be translated as is noted in the article.  If this happens, you end up with an empty function body.  You must hand code these translations.